# Creating a class in custom template for Qt Creator new project wizard?

Tags: c++, qt, project, qt-creator, wizard

I've created a custom template for Qt Creator wizard which contains three files:

- main.cpp
- project.pro
- wizard.xml

Now I'd also like to include a class to the project when the project is created.
This class (including `.h` and `.cpp` files) should be named based on the user's input in the wizard.

I already managed to create the wizard for asking the class's name:

```
<fields>
    <field mandatory="true" name="CLASS">
        <fieldcontrol class="QLineEdit" defaulttext="MyClass" />
        <fielddescription>Class name:</fielddescription>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Now how do I create `.h` and `.cpp` files from the user input?

Comment: So... You're trying to create a code-generator?  Your question is very confusing to me.

Comment: @Huytard Qt Creator supports [custom wizards](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-wizards/) for creating projects. I'm trying to make my own which also creates a class when ever a new project is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, similar to the link you posted, what you want [to do seems to be in the documentation already](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-project-wizards.html#creating-class-wizards)

Since you have your field named CLASS:

```
 <field mandatory="true" name="CLASS">
```

You then use that field as the target of a file:

```
 <files>
     <file source="default.cpp" target="%CLASS:l%..%CppSourceSuffix%"  openeditor="true" />
     <file source="default.h" target="%CLASS:l%.%CppHeaderSuffix%"  openeditor="true" />
 </files>
```

Maybe you can try to modify an existing template first instead of creating from scratch?

Comment: Wow I'm stupid, thanks! I will make sure to take a deeper look at the existing templates :P